# In Xcode why is my object placement dependent on what device I have selected for the storyboard

Tags: swift, uikit, storyboard

I am developing an iOS app where I am drawing lines to objects placed arbitrarily on the screen. This appears to work fine if the device I am using as the simulator is the same as the one I have selected for the display of the storyboard. However, if I have them mismatched the lines are offset by a large amount. I am guessing that the position of the lines is calculated using the original position of the objects, rather than the positions assigned by autolayout at the new screen size. What can I do to start the lines from the positions of the objects regardless of device selected?

For reference, though it shouldn't matter, my line creation code:

```
let newLine = SkillLine(frame: background.frame, x1: skillButton1.layer.position.x, y1: skillButton1.layer.position.y, x2: skillButton2.layer.position.x, y2: skillButton2.layer.position.y, startButton: skillButton1, endButton: skillButton2)
```

The actual line drawing:

```
context!.setStrokeColor(color.cgColor)
context!.setLineWidth(3)
context!.beginPath()
context!.move(to: CGPoint(x: x1, y: y1)) // This would be oldX, oldY
context!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x2, y: y2)) // This would be newX, newY
context!.strokePath()
```

What I want:

[image: What I want]

What I get:

[image: What I get]

I have tried to change up how I am defining the centers of the objects and how their constraints are defined, but that doesn't seem to matter. I was origionally always getting the offset, but now I only get it with mismatched devices. Currently the x and y contraints on the objects are all multipliers on the center of the background, and they show in the correct place regardless of device.

Comment: You are not providing any details to allow anyone to help diagnose the issue. Please update your question showing the relevant portion of the storyboard and the relevant constraints. Show relevant code that is supposed to determine the points for the lines.

Comment: instead of using the screen as a reference to draw the lines, use the background image or the view that you want to actually reflect the details on and give it a fix position, if you have the (X, Y) of the points you want to connect that would be better, but yeah i agree with @HangarRash we need more details

Comment: Kristopher  - without seeing your actual code, it is difficult to help. However, it appears the line-points are offset from the view. Change `let newLine = SkillLine(frame: background.frame, x1: ...` to `let newLine = SkillLine(frame: background.bounds, x1: ...` (use **.bounds** instead of **.frame**).